# Find a number of students whose grades are higher (interview question)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is the interview question:

> A tuple represents a student with grades in each subject.
> (100, 100, 100) means that a student got 100 in all subjects.
>
> Given a list of students, remove a student that has lower grades than all other students in all subjects. Repeat until there is no student that gets removed.
>
> Then, return the number of remaining students.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> input:
>
> ```
> [(90, 53, 88), (60, 60, 60), (55, 48, 59)]
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> The first student is not removed because
>
> - the first grade (90) is higher than that of the second and third student (60 and 55, respectively).
> - the third grade (88) is higher than that of the second and third student (60 and 59, respectively).
>
> The second student is not removed because
>
> - the first grade (60) is higher than that of the third student (55).
> - the third grade (60) is higher than that of the third student (59).
>
> The third student is removed because all grades are lower than all other students.
>
> #### Example 2
>
> This is the same as the first example except the fourth student (new student)
>
> input:
>
> ```
> [(90, 53, 88), (60, 60, 60), (55, 48, 59), (40, 40, 40)]
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> The fourth student is removed because all grades are lower than all other students.
>
> Now, the rest is the same as "Example 1"

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Maybe you're interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_of_a_point_set

Comment: I think the question was intentionally phrased backwards by the interviewer. Rather than thinking about removing students you don't want, think about picking students you want.

Comment: Question is not clear : "...than others in all subjects" at the same time? There is only one, isn't it? (Or several with the exact same grades, no?)

Comment: I think that it is asking to remove all ["dominated"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_dominance) entries.  But it's unclear because the word "*others*" in the phrase "*lower grades than* others *in all subjects.*" is ambiguous,  Do they mean lower than *any others* or lower than *all others*?  It's not clear, but I would tend toward the former.

Comment: If this is about strategic dominance, then as far as I know it's asking for the IESDS algorithm which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Well, the OP has not been online in the hour after posting their question, so... moving on.

Comment: Sorry for writing an ambiguous question :'( I found the snippet I copied during the interview and edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the input is [98,100,100][100,98,100][99,90,90][1,2,1][2,1,2] and the answer is 5
you can simple do a while and if there's a student at the bottom in all scores and the list is higher then 1,remove hem

```
[n=num of students]
[M=num of exams]
sort will cost=O(M*nlogn)
remove bottom=O(M*(n-1))~o(M*n)
total run time cost= O(M*nlogn)
```

if the answer is 2 cause [98,100,100][100,98,100] have something in top,
simply check each subject and take the top student

if the answer is 3 cause [98,100,100][100,98,100][99,90,90] are better in any subject then:
[1,2,1][2,1,2]
the solution i gave below can help but its more complicated

solution: i would try to sort each exam ,
after that check each student,  how many below hem have moved above hem between the current exam and the next exam,
create an edge between the student and those students, create a graph and added the edges,after finishing with all the exams and adding it to the graph, then run BFS from the first student at the first exam,everytime u find a student,keep hem,after the run is over,return all the students the BFS found,

example :
(A B C D E F ,are students,EX1 EX2 EX3 are the subjects)

```
EX1:-----EX2:-----EX3:
A:90-----B:60-----C:70
B:60-----C:53-----D:65
C:55-----A:48-----B:60
D:20-----D:30-----A:55
E:10-----F:15-----E:20
F:5------E:10-----F:7
```

between first and sec exam ,student A moved from index 1,to 3  in the list,
so I'm creating an edge between A to B (A,B), and A to C(A,C)
and adding it to my array,
same with (E,F) cause E moved from 5 to 6, and F is now at 5 ,

```
my array :(A,B),(A,C),(E,F)
```

same with EX2 and EX3

```
adding : (B,D)(B,C)(A,B)(F,E)
```

my final array will be[after removing doubles] :

```
(A,B),(A,C),(E,F),(B,D),(B,C),(F,E)
```

after that i  will add A to my result and run BFS From A, each new latter i find, I add to my result,

```
the result will be :A,B,C,D
```

mean the answer will be 4

Answer (score 0):

> Given a list of students, remove a student that has lower grades than
> **all other** students in **all subjects**. Repeat until there is no student
> that gets removed.

Make an array of each grade with a grade, student pair, so long as all the grade arrays lowest value is from the same student remove the student.

Pseudo code ahead

```
for each grade
  sort grade
while lowest of all grade is same student
  remove student.
```